# Sphinx autodoc not importing modules

Tags: django, autodoc

I am writing some documentation for a Django project using Sphinx.

My project (Django 1.4) looks like this:

```
/funproject
   /documentation
       # this is where sphinx files live
       /source
           conf.py
           ... 
   /funproject
       __init__.py
       settings.py
       admin.py
       models.py
   /app1
   /app2
   fabfile.py
   manage.py
```

I have Sphinx setup in the conf.py:

```
 import sys, os

 sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))

 os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'funproject.settings'

 from funproject import settings
 from django.core.management import setup_environ
 setup_environ(settings)
```

So in my Sphinx source files I can do this:

```
 .. automodule:: app1.models
    :members:
```

which works fine. However, these two examples do not work:

1.

```
 .. automodule:: funproject.models
    :members:
```

2. 

```
 .. automodule:: fabfile
    :members:
```

The second works if I move the fabfile into app1 and use `app1.fabfile`

I'm guessing I have some issue with my `conf.py` but I have tried many derivations but I cannot import my `fabfile.py` unless it is under an app dir (though under `/funproject` it doesn't work either).

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the fabric fabfile directory style? Perhaps it's the case that automodule doesn't look at single file modules? Docs on this other style are [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/fabfiles.html?highlight=fabfile#fabfile-discovery)